# How to add test case in existing test run through automation

Tags: rally

I have created on test set and i want to add test case in existing test run . I used update request  to add the test case, but its deleting existing test case in test run and adding it.

```
if(!testCaseList.isJsonNull()&&!update){
            restApi.setApplicationName("PSN")
            JsonObject newTS = new JsonObject()
            newTS.addProperty("Name", TSName)
            newTS.addProperty("PlanEstimate", points)
            newTS.addProperty("Project", projectRef)
            newTS.addProperty("Owner", userRef)
            if (releaseRef!="") newTS.addProperty("Release", releaseRef)
            if (iterationRef!="") newTS.addProperty("Iteration", iterationRef)
            newTS.add("TestCases", testCaseList)
            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testset",newTS)
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest)
            ref = createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()
        }
        else if(!testCaseList.isJsonNull()&&update){
            restApi.setApplicationName("PSN")
            newTS.addProperty("Name", TSName)
            newTS.addProperty("PlanEstimate", points)
            newTS.addProperty("Project", projectRef)
            newTS.addProperty("Owner", userRef)
            if (releaseRef!="") newTS.addProperty("Release", releaseRef)
            if (iterationRef!="") newTS.addProperty("Iteration", iterationRef)
            newTS.add("TestCases", testCaseList)
            UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(ref,newTS)
            UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateRequest)
            ref = updateResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting the TestCases collection directly you want to use the CollectionUpdateRequest and the updateCollection method.

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#update-collection

```
CollectionUpdateRequest testsetTestCasesAddRequest = new CollectionUpdateRequest(ref + "/testcases", testCaseList, true);
CollectionUpdateResponse testsetTestCasesAddResponse = restApi.updateCollection(testsetTestCasesAddRequest);
```